# Can a Master of Many Styles still Fuse Styles while wearing armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

Master of Many Styles, a monk archetype, has a class ability called Fuse Styles:

> The master of many styles can have two style feat stances active at once. Starting a stance provided by a style feat is still a swift action, but when the master of many styles switches to another style feat, he can choose one style whose stance is already active to persist. He may only have two style feat stances active at a time.

The ability replaces Flurry of Blows, which is removed when the monk would wear armor. Thus the question: Can our master of many styles use armor and fuse styles at the same time?

Comment: +1 I can't find any reason for this not to work, but also can't find confirmation it works in armor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) archetype [master of many styles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/master-of-many-styles)'s extraordinary ability fuse styles says that it replaces the typical monk's [flurry of blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) *and* because the ability fuse styles mentions nothing about it being obviated by armor, a master of many styles should be able to employ the ability fuse styles even while wearing armor.

However, while wearing *any* armor, the master of many styles monk won't benefit from the special abilities AC bonus and fast movement and at level 2, if wearing armor heavier than light, won't benefit from the special ability [evasion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Evasion-Ex-). And there's the fact that monks generally lack proficiency with any armor.

Of course, this of little concern to, for example, the typical Wisdom 10 fighter that's only ever taking but a lone level of master of many styles monk pretty much solely for the ability fuse styles. Such a warrior will find himself having lost very little from armoring up.